# Вывод в консоль значений экземпляров класса (как аналога массива структуры C++) Java

Tags: java, c++, массивы, структуры

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: перевожу задачу работы со структурами с C++ на Java, не получается один момент. Как аналог структуре C++ использую класс Book, создаю массив Book[] arr c четырьмя элементами - экземплярами класса Book, каждому через конструктор задаю значения и пытаюсь отдельным методом вывести в консоль. При этом в консоль выводится последний заполненный элемент массива arr.length-раз.

Что не так, почему первые три элемента массива не выводятся?

```
public class Main {
public static int n = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book[] arr = new Book[n];
    arr[0] = new Book (1, "Vinin", "Самоучитель по C++", 2001, 5 );
    arr[1] = new Book (2, "Bikov", "Самоучитель по Java", 2002, 6 );
    arr[2] = new Book (3, "Andreev", "Самоучитель по Python", 2003, 7 );
    arr[3] = new Book (4, "Andreev", "Самоучитель по C#", 2004, 8);

    output(arr);
}

private static void output(Book a[]){
    System.out.printf("%-4s%-1s%-8s%-1s%-27s%-1s%-8s%-1s%-8s%n", "id", "|", "Автор", "|", "Название", "|", "Год", "|", "Стеллаж|");
    System.out.println("___________________________________________________________");
    for (int i =0; i<a.length; i++)
    System.out.printf("%-4d%-1s%-8s%-1s%-27s%-1s%-8d%-1s%-7d%-1s%n", a[i].id, "|", a[i].author, "|", a[i].title, "|", a[i].year, "|", a[i].position, "|");
}
}

class Book{
public static int id;
public static String author;
public static String title;
public static int year;
public static int position;

public Book(int id, String author, String title, int year, int position) {
    this.id = id;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.position = position;
}
}

    Результат:
    id  |Автор   |Название                   |Год     |Стеллаж|
    ___________________________________________________________
    4   |Andreev |Самоучитель по C#          |2004    |8      |
    4   |Andreev |Самоучитель по C#          |2004    |8      |
    4   |Andreev |Самоучитель по C#          |2004    |8      |
    4   |Andreev |Самоучитель по C#          |2004    |8      |
```

Comment: почитайте про ключевое слово `static`

Comment: гайз, нам нужен канонический вопрос-ответ по статику, чтобы закрывать такие вопросы :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin Пиши :) Час назад был такой же вопрос

Comment: @AlexChermenin Я нашел внятный ответ. Можно на него все цеплять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите `static` из объявлений полей. Должно быть так

```
class Book{
  public int id;
  public String author;
  public String title;
  public int year;
  public int position;
```

Comment: Спасибо!)) понял ошибку)

Comment: @Aleksandr Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный

Comment: жду - временное ограничение)